# EasyAPNS initially setting all flags to disabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification

We're using [EasyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/apple-delegate) to help us with push notifications in our iPhone app, being sent from our PHP web app.

On first installation of the app, the user sees the request to allow us to send push notifications, even if they select allow, all the flags are sent to the web server from the iPhone as 'disabled'.

If you terminate the app, and reopen it, when it sends the settings again... they are sent as the correct options (e.g., enabled)

We followed the steps exactly, with one small difference, that we are using
    `application:didfinishlaunchingwithoptions:`
instead of
    `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

As it's apparenly deprecated according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Can anybody shed some light on this, and point us in the right direction for a fix?

Answer (score 0):

So if the user rejects push messaging, you will re-ask when the app is next used after termination? It may get a little annoying for the user to be asked the same question over and over again.

And you will have to ask for permission or else that user wouldn't be registered for Push.

Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: It correctly only asks the first time they install the app, what I'm saying is that even if they accept the request, the app sends to the web app flags saying they denied the request. Next time they open the app (after terminating) they aren't asked again, it's just the settings being sent to the server again... this time though, correctly.